# Kerning issue in soul \hl with \emph

Tags: highlighting, kerning, soul, emphasis

The text is little squashed when using `\hl` with `\emph`, but only with particular words which makes me think this is a kerning issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

% OK
\hl{foobar}

% OK
\hl{\textbf{foobar}}

% OK
\hl{\emph{foobar}}

% Kerning off.
\hl{\emph{requested}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kerning is involved but the main problem is that soul does the highlighting by syllable (to allow hyphenation) and so the background of "quested" overprints the first syllable. Imho there is not much you can do beside suppressing hyphenation e.g. with an \mbox or inserting more space.

Comment: Note also that the 2nd `o` in the 3rd is overprinted by a yellow box.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer wrapping the offending word in a `\mbox` does appear to resolve the problem. It sounds like that might be my only choice.

Comment: Unless there is a way to patch the `\emph` command to include `\mbox`.

Comment: `\mbox` would suppress breaking at hyphens at the end of a line (which `soul` does allow), but even there the clipping at the end of a syllable is evident before the hyphen -- add this line to the example: `xxx \hspace{.85\linewidth} \hl{\emph{requested}}`.  too bad.

Comment: @Moriambar Do we really count that as a good solution? Maybe one should rather answer it than close it with a bad solution in the comments.

Comment: @TeXnician I count it as an *excellent* solution, since highlighting a word has no meaning if hyphenating, except when long paragraphs are all highlighted, which could create a new solution indeed. I think that for a single-word approach `mbox` is really conceptually good: highlighting is usual for display

Comment: @Moriambar As I understand soul one uses it, if he *wants* breaking, and not using f.i. a colorbox. But you'll find your close voters without my vote eitherway ;)

Comment: @Moriambar Solving a question in the comments is AFAIK not a close reason.

Comment: @TeXnician oh, I understand what you mean. That's why there's a community approach to this votes. One can only know that much. Thanks for clarifying, I'm retracting the vote