# Why does the text overlap?

Tags: xetex, highlighting, soul

It may not be easy to see, but the error is definitely there -- look at the "r" in "Nordamerikas":

[image]

How can I remedy this? This was brought to my attention during a final check of something that is to be printed, so I would prefer a solution that keeps everything as it is, except of course the error ...

MWE (please compile with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{color,soul}

\begin{document}

Boreali-Americana {[}\hl{\emph{Nordamerikas flora}}{]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (there are more than one `r` in `Nordamerikas` ;-) )

Comment: It seems to only be related to `color` + `soul` as the problem remains if `microtype` and `Baskervaldx` are removed. Also not sure whether `fontenv` should be used with `xelatex/lualatex`

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470311/how-to-fix-scrlayer-scrpage-microtype-kerning-issue . It may help you to solve the issue adapting the `microtype` settings.

Comment: You're right @daleif : `fontenc` shouldn't be used on XeTeX/LuaTeX.  Those engines use `fontspec` to handle the fonts used.

Comment: @alchemist if I remove `microtype` al together I can still recreate the problem.

Comment: Using lualatex + lua-ul + luacolor instead of soul seems to work just fine.

Comment: In the original problem, As soon as the string is `Nordam` then then `r` gets broken, if it is just `Norda` then the `r` is normal.

Comment: Use `\hl{\mbox{\emph{Nordamerikas flora}}}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266666/kerning-issue-in-soul-hl-with-emph.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to more directly to `lualatex` and use `lua-ul` instead? `soul` does not seem super future proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Marijn's suggestion, this MWE should do the job:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{color,soulpos}

\ulposdef{\myhl}{%
    \mbox{%
        \color{yellow}%
        \rule[-.8ex]{\ulwidth}{11pt}}}

\begin{document}
    
    Boreali-Americana {[}\hl{\emph{Nordamerikas flora}}{]}
    
    Boreali-Americana {[}\myhl{\emph{Nordamerikas flora}}{]}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: using soulpos]

However, as you said in your question you were compiling using `XeTeX`, the more future prove approach would be converting your preamble to be used under `LuaLaTeX` (as daleif already mentioned in the comments). That conversion of the provided MWE to `LuaLaTeX` would look like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Baskervaldx}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Reg,
    ItalicFont = *-Ita,
    BoldFont = *-Bol,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BolIta]

\usepackage{luacolor} % required by lua-ul (loads xcolor)
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}
    
    Boreali-Americana [\highLight[yellow]{\emph{Nordamerikas flora}}]
    
\end{document}
```

Every decent TeX editor has a `search and replace` option that can be used to change `{]}\hl` to `[\highLight` and to change `{]}` to `]`. So I guess it wouldn't be a great impact on your document.